# unlink() won't delete file from database

Tags: laravel

I am having problems with unlink() I have used before and worked fine but in this particular one it isn't. will explain.

this is the code

```
public function kill($id){

$post = Post::withTrashed()->where('id', $id)->first();



unlink(public_path(). "/" . $post->featured);

$post->forceDelete();

Session::flash('success', 'Post has been permanently deleted');

return redirect()->back();
}
```

and i get this error
ErrorException in PostsController.php line 158:
unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/angie/public/http://angie.dev/uploads/posts/1506133455image_1.jpg): No such file or directory

so basically is adding "http://angie.dev/" before file name. however looking in the database file name is normal. how do I get rid of it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
unlink(public_path(). str_replace("angie.dev/","/", $post->featured));
```

Comment: it actually the other way round. but thanks for your help

unlink(public_path().  str_replace("http://angie.dev/","/", $post->featured));